# Can we use some inbuilt Configuration Management in CDH than using Chef/Puppet

Tags: hadoop

I'm new to Hadoop, moved from Linux.
really dont know if this is stupid but do we have CDH tools for config management (something inbuilt) or do we need a 3rd party integration like chef/puppet.
same for monitoring do we need to tools like nagios or is CDM enough.

Regards
Aina Lester

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try [Cloudera Manager](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/products-and-services/cloudera-enterprise/cloudera-manager.html) for Cluster Management/Monitoring/Alerting/Change Management/Auditing.

There are 2 variants of Cloudera Manager(CM):

- [CM Express](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/products-and-services/cloudera-express.html): Free and best to get started with. Provides Deployment & Configuration, Management, Monitoring & Diagnostic Tools
- [CM Enterprise](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/products-and-services/cloudera-enterprise.html): Annual subscription per Node. Provides CM Express functionality + Advanced Management Features & Support.